# Laravel send default email ( without SMTP )

Tags: php, email, laravel

it's possible in laravel to send a default php email without the smtp config ? Like in php with X-Mailer ?

Comment: Don't know why this was down-voted, it's a perfectly good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the standard PHP mail() function for situations when I want to specify the sender email hardly:

```
$to = env('MAIL_USERNAME'); 
$subject = $request->title; 
$message = $request->message; 
$headers = 'From: ' . $request->email . "\r\n" . 
'Reply-To: ' . $request->email . "\r\n" . 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Comment: I like and use this solution, was only curious if laravel can do it. Thanks anyway.